# Synthesis global instance count

Tags: vhdl, verilog, hdl, synthesis

I couldn't find any questions related to this, but it is possible that I just don't know what to search for. When using a synthesis tool (let's say Synplify if you need a specific tool but it would be best if there were a standard compliant version that worked across tools), is it possible to keep track of the number of instances of a module and help this guide the synthesis? I suspect not, but I can see many use-cases for something like this. Let me give some examples of what I mean.

Some context, I am writing this with FPGA development in mind, but I bet it would have uses for ASIC designs as well.

Let's say that I have 10 multipliers on a device and I have some operation (like a complex multiplier) that I want to instantiate in many locations (not just in a generate loop, but all over the design). Let's say that I have one implementation using the dedicated multipliers for this function, but I also have a complex multiplier that uses the fabric. I would like my complex multipliers to exhaust the dedicated multipliers before going over to the fabric implementation.

Is it possible to instantiate the complex multipliers through a wrapper, and every time this wrapper is instantiated during elaboration, a global instance count is incremented so I can keep track of how many multipliers have been used? Furthermore, can I then use this global variable in a generate-if statement or some other construct to make a decision between the two implementations based on the number of instances of the multiplier module that have been used?

I'm using the multiplier as an example. I realize that I could just infer the multiplier to obtain this behavior. I imagine designs where I might want to infer different filter structures (for example, a tapped delay line FIR filter versus a distributed arithmetic FIR filter) based on the current value of this global variable. This would certainly help when porting code across to new FPGAs.

I've been looking for something like this for a while, but I suspect it doesn't exist. I realize I can do something very close to what I want by simply designing the architecture of my system the right way. The intention here is more about automating that process in my design so that future alterations to my design don't require me to refactor the whole system layout (unless timing or resource limitations come into play). I also see this as a means of helping me to keep my code portable among devices in the same family with very different resource allocations (this one has more DSP slices, that one has more LUTs, etc.).

If this only exists in one tool or one language, that would still be an acceptable solution to me. If you can provide definitive proof or a logical reason why it can't work, that would also be an acceptable solution to me.

Comment: See a related question [Are there any VHDL resource usage profiling tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907940/are-there-any-vhdl-resource-usage-profiling-tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually tried implementing a design that infers more multipliers than there are in the device? I would expect the tool to automatically start using LUT resource once it runs out of DSP blocks. However, assuming this does not happen:

You can achieve this to an extent using Xilinx Vivado and a custom TCL script. I won't detail the exact commands and script, as this would be time consuming to get right, but the basic flow would look like this:

1. Add `generic` parameters to the entities that implement multipliers. Tie these through to `generic` parameters on the top level of the design.
2. Script sets an initial set of generic parameters that cause every entity to use dedicated DSP blocks.
3. Script runs `synth_design` with the `-generic` switch controlling the DSP block usage.
4. After synthesis completes, script parses output of `report_utilization` to determine if the number of DSP blocks was exceeded. If not, go to step 5. If yes, modify the set of generic parameters such that more entities use an alternative multiplier implementation, and go back to step 3.
5. Synthesized design fits in device, script proceeds with implementation steps.

An alternative to the above process without using generics would be to keep the same basic steps, but use the `set_property` command on specific multiplier instances in order to control their implementation, instead of setting generics.

Comment: I should not have used the multiplier example. I know that multiplier inference gives me this feature basically. I envision this feature as a way to automatically architect much larger components in my design. My basic usage case is for hardware acceleration. I have accumulated many dev boards from different families, and I want to run the same computational code on all of them (barring other issues). The other example is a better usage case. A tool can't know to switch my multiply-accumulate chain into a distributed arithmetic filter on its own. I'll revise the question when I have time.

Comment: @hops I think my answer would apply to that case as well. Whatever resource you are running out of, a script can ascertain this, and use generics or some other method modify the design as appropriate, based on a set of rules that form part of the script. It's not *exactly* what you asked for, but I think it's the closest you're going to get.

Comment: It is very close to what I am looking for you are right. In fact, I've already done this with scripting before. That's where I got the idea. I could accept this as an answer. I do wish I could find some sort of logical reason or a line in a standards document or tool literature that proves it isn't possible with pure HDL.

Comment: I will accept this answer if I do not receive an answer with evidential proof of the impossibility in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after does not exist. However, there are a few comments that can be made.

Firstly, you should be able to estimate (within reason) the amount of resources required to implement your design. If it exceeds the capacity of your chip, you may need to rethink the design or upgrade. Secondly, if you try to implement a design and you utilise all of the DSP resources (inferring multipliers, for example), the Synthesis tools are smart enough such that they will attempt to "fit" the remaining components in general logic. This can have a number of undesired consequences; Combinational logic can blow out quickly (depending on what you are implementing), and it is almost guaranteed that there will be a significant impact on the maximum clock frequency. Lastly, and this point is more relevant if you want to explicitly control how things are implemented, you can use synthesis directives (which will vary between vendor/language).

An example of a directive to use DSP resources (for Altera devices, in VHDL) would be [(taken from here)](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_multstyle.htm):

```
signal a, b : unsigned(8 downto 0);
signal res : unsigned(17 downto 0);
attribute multstyle : string;
attribute multstyle of res : signal is "dsp"; -- Alternatively, use "logic"
res <= a * b;
```

If, for example, you had a "complex multiplier" module that you wanted to control how it was implemented, you could use a generic to control it (when instantiated).

```
entity complex_mult is
   generic(
      MULT_TYPE : string := "dsp"
   );
   port(
      ...
   );
end entity;

architecture rtl of complex_mult is

begin

   signal my_res : unsigned(15 downto 0); -- Obviously define res width depending on what you are doing
   attribute multstyle : string;
   attribute multstyle of my_res : signal is MULT_TYPE;
   -- Do stuff
end rtl;
```

Comment: Your additional comments are basically what I was getting at in the paragraph that says "I realize I can do something very close to what I want by simply designing the architecture of my system the right way." But the reason I want this feature is to use the same HDL codebase (top level and modules, etc.) to target different chips. I suspect that you are correct that it is not possible (since I've been looking for it for a long time). I could accept your answer if it provided some sort of evidence that this is not possible rather than simply stating that it is not possible.

Comment: The synthesis directives (in Altera; AKA synthesis attributes in Xilinx) are the vendors way of providing hints to the synthesis tools (or "guiding" the synthesis tool, as you say). There is no option to achieve what you want ([Xilinx](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_4/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) , [Altera](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.1/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir.htm))